# UriPathExtensionMapping Web API 2

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web API 2.1, I have successfully used CORS and UriPathExtensionMapping. But i would like to access my api resources as query string parameters as well i.e.

http://example.com/test/api/Employee

http://example.com/test/api/Employee?id=10

http://example.com/test/api/Employee.json

http://example.com/test/api/Employee.xml

http://example.com/test/api/Employee.json?id=10

http://example.com/test/api/Employee.xml?id=10&name=someone

http://example.com/test/api/Employee.json?id=10&name=someone

All above mentioned resources is how i want them to use. I am able to use 1,2,3,4 however after that with extension and query string it does not seem to work.

Below is my WebApiConfig.cs code.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiUriPathExtension",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{ext}",
            defaults: new { ext = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);

        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "text/xml");
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
```

What am i missing, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what did you mean by `it does not seem to work`?..also if you expect the value of `id` to come from query string , you should not put it as part of the route templates as route templates do `not` look for querystring during route matching...

Comment: Thanks Kiran i hoped you reply and you did. Coming to the error i am getting "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." I changed the above code inline with what i actually have after your comments still i get the same error.

Comment: also i not only have id sometime i have some other query parameters like name, age etc. I am not having it as part of the route template. infact the method/resources in my api controller are with the parameters and hence if i pass those in the query string with above route definition i thought it would work.

Comment: I noticed that you made a change which is too broad now :-)...like you would need to handle requests like `api/employee` too, so you should still have 2 routes defined...my earlier comment was only about removing `id` from the two routes...also when you do `api/employee.json` do you get back json content?...i want to make sure this works because if you are on IIS, having a `.` in the url causes other modules IIS come into picture and you would see `404 Not Found` responses...

Comment: My apologies, i now modified it again, hopefully last time :). What i am trying to achieve is that use it as a normal resource and defaults the response as json and if i qualify it with an ext i.e. json/xml it returns the desired format. Also i wish to have the ability to choose the format and also use the query strings.

Comment: If i use api/Employee (or) api/Employee?id=10 i get json back, however if i use api/Employee.json (or) api/Employee.json?id=10 (or) api/Employee.xml?id=10 i get "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: Ok...seems like you are hitting the `.` issue that was referring earlier...one solution is to have `<system.webServer><modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>` in your web.config and this should solve your issue...

Comment: Thanks man it works well however if i have both routes then api/Employee works but api/Employee.json/.xml does not. But if i comment the default route then api/Employee does not work but all others does. If there is a way to make both work. The error i get is

{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '..../api/Employee.json'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'Employee.json'."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last comment, looks like the order of the routes are not correct...following is an example of how can order them:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiWithExtension",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{ext}");

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);

config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "application/xml");
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
```

Comment: Thanks a ton again for the quick turn around you are a champ.

Comment: Hi Kiran, i have a requirement to actually config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiIdOnly",
                routeTemplate: "{api}/{id}.{ext}"
            );
which is equivalent to config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiWithId",
                routeTemplate: "{api}/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Also i want to show data in HTML format instead of json or xml do i need to write custom media formatter?

can you please help me.